# Installation of AVD emulator in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to install Android emulator in Android studio using the zip file that I have manually downloaded from the Android studio download repository. Please give me a step-by-step guide to accomplish this.

Comment: [This thread has the correct answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686444/android-studio-manually-download-system-image-for-emulator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686444/android-studio-manually-download-system-image-for-emulator Visit this page to get the correct answers

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the zip file, first thing is to unzip its content (a folder named "emulator") in your SDK folder. Path to this folder is shown in your Android Studio System Settings.

Next, I found that a file named package.xml is needed for the SDK manager to acknowledge that the emulator has been installed; you can get a template here :
https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/emulator/package.xml

Open this file and make sure you modify the revision number to match your emulator  version, found in the file "source.properties".
ie.: `<revision><major>29</major><minor>0</minor><micro>11</micro></revision>`

Move the package.xml in the emulator folder.

That should be enough for you to complete your Android Studio setup.